# Umbraco Support Area

Tags: umbraco

I've worked on an Umbraco site in the past and had a content area at the root that was used for support information such as email content.

I cannot remember what the document type is? Does anyone have any ideas about this. I've tried created a new node at the base, but this has a url, and replaces my main home url.

Ta

Comment: Which version of Umbraco are you using?

Comment: 7.1.x, latest version that come from nuget.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the root node and then go to the properties section. The document type should be listed there.

Comment: Thats all fine but its more for this scenario. The end user needs to manage the content of a drop-down list, but doesn't know how to use a database. This area wold contain the drop-down list content, but this content would never be published to be viewable on a page, just as a drop-down. So there would be two root nodes, but one root node is just for supporting data.